# The Code Works Fine When Debugging, But it Doesn't work when it runs without Debugging

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, debugging

```
  string entry = Titleentry.Text;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bookdepository.com/search/advanced");

        //HtmlElementCollection bookCollection;

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        HtmlElementCollection bookCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in bookCollection)
        {
            if ((curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "searchTitle"))
            {
                curElement.SetAttribute("value", entry);
            }
        }



        HtmlElementCollection filterCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("filterSortBy").GetElementsByTagName("option");
        List<HtmlElement> filterList = new List<HtmlElement>();
        foreach (HtmlElement filterItem in filterCollection) { filterList.Add(filterItem); }
        HtmlElement filterElement =
          (HtmlElement)filterList.Where(filterOption => filterOption.GetAttribute("value").Equals("price_low_high", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();

        if (filterElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("price_low_high"))
        {
            filterElement.SetAttribute("Selected", "price_low_high");
            filterElement.InvokeMember("click");
        }

        bookCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in bookCollection)
        {
            if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("searchSubmit"))
            {
                curElement.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Loaded");

        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Start();
        myTimer.Stop();

        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) //from here on the code doesnt work.
        {
            HtmlElementCollection avCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("filterAvailability").GetElementsByTagName("option");

            List<HtmlElement> avList = new List<HtmlElement>();
            foreach(HtmlElement avItem in avCollection)
            {
                avList.Add(avItem);
            }

            HtmlElement avElement =
                (HtmlElement)avList.Where(avOption => avOption.GetAttribute("value").Equals("1")).SingleOrDefault();

            if (avElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("1"))
            {
                avElement.SetAttribute("Selected", "1");
                avElement.InvokeMember("click");
            }

            bookCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
            foreach (HtmlElement curElement in bookCollection)
            {
                if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("searchSubmit"))
                {
                    curElement.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the whole code. I tried setting the delay with timer thinking because it is reacting too fast but the timer is also not working so im not sure what the problem could be.

the code that doesnt work is suppose to create the avList with 3 counts and choose the value 1. the value 1 represents the In Stock availability of the website.

when running without debugging it seems to completely ignore the code written in the if condition.

thanks

Comment: Be careful with the webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete while statement. Though unlikely in this situation, code like this can create an infinite loop as the condition might never be Complete, such as staying Uninitialized

Comment: i see. but i think thats very unlikely to happen

Comment: What is the WebBrowserReadyState value in the if statement? From what I can tell the state has changed in the time it takes to break out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the issue looks to be with the way you setup your code. You are trying to do things one after the other which is yielding some strange results. It is best to allow the API (WebBrowser) tell you what is going on rather than trying to query it until it is done.

Having a loop to check "are you done yet?" is considered back practice because it blocks your code and occupies the processor with a wasteful wait loop.

What you need to do, is look through the documentation for the WebBrowser API and figure out how the WebBrowser communicates back to the calling class. C# takes a huge advantage of Events and Delgates, so my suggestion is to look to see if there is an event for what you are looking for. A quick search came up with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.ondocumentcompleted.aspx

This is far move manageable approach than to spin a while loop until the condition is met. Let the API inform you when it's done and then you can decide what to do with it. As for your events, here is an example of how the event is wired:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown.aspx

so you do not have to check for them in a loop, eating up processing time.

Also, since your in the .NET world you have access to linq. You don't have to write out your loops in order to find something. For instance:

```
    //Note: I have not tested this code, but this is close to what it should look like
    bookCollection.where(x => x.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "searchTitle")
              .ForEach(x => x.SetAttribute("value", entry));
```

I cannot vouch for how fast this is, but LINQ tends to clean up the logic for looping and searching.

=====================================

If you insist of having your code, the issue arises from

```
     webBrowser1.ReadyState
```

which is no longer in the "Complete" state. However, your while loop already checks for this condition right above, so you can just remove the IF statement. The reason I told you that you have an iffy while loop is for this exact reason. The enum value is there so that you can query the WebBrowser process while it is still processing. This is useful in multithreaded software. However, my guess is that the flag is flipped to

```
   webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
```

right before the page is displayed. That would explain why your while loop picks up on it and exists out. Now, the issue is that it will probably flip the enum to Uninitialized because it is finished loading the page and has disconnected the socket connection. This would put it into the Unintialized state. This API relies on a state machine pattern and the sequence of the states are are probably different from what you think they are. Here is more information about state machine:

[Simple state machine example in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923767/simple-state-machine-example-in-c)

I hope this helps!

Comment: wow this has been great help. I used the even handler like you mentioned. it works perfect now but how do I make the even stop once it is completed? The page keeps refreshing because at the end of that event handler the code submits the search button. Since i used: private void OnDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) it will continue to go through the code everytime the document is completed

Comment: Hmmm. For the search button submit, are you assigning the same event handler or reusing the same WebBrowser object? If so, simply have a bool in your class that is "bool formSubmitted = false". Flip this bool when you submit the form. In the event, check if this is true/false, and if it is, don't execute the logic inside.

Comment: im reusing the same webbrowser object. ill give the bool a try. It seems that even is looping itself as it is not paying attention for the bool statement. If i use webbrowser.stop it stops before the refresh of the page(obviously) is there a turn around to this?