# Developing custom protocol in c#

Tags: command, protocols

I need to develop a custom protocol GUI in c#, which involves creating sync byte, header, and payload and crc for the data to be sent. This will be sent over RS232 to the device. This is a PC to device protocol mostly commands and i need to keep tab on sequence number for each command etc.

i am pretty much new to c#. I would like to get some pointers on the state machine implementation. thanks in advance

Comment: The main thing is to separate the implementation of the protocol (which will probably require a state machine) from the sending and receiving of the serial data, which should work asynchronously and the data queued for the protocol handler.

Comment: Here's a simple implementation of a state machine in C#

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923767/simple-state-machine-example-in-c