# There are some method to use toggle buttons without need to create a lot of conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, jtogglebutton

I'm developing a program in java for admin orders in a restaurant.
I have a screen like this.
[Frame for admin orders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3xrc.png)

I want to select any button from left and any button from right and clic in button "Agregar" later.
I'm thinking to do a method with a lot of conditions if and else if, for example.

```
if(buttonCombo1.isSelected() and buttonNumber1.isSelected()){
//Doing something
}else if(buttonCombo1.isSelected() and buttonNumber2.isSelected()){
//Doing something
}
```

I would have to do a lot of conditions, and I have no idea do otherwise.
If you can help me to find another way for do It, I would be grateful.

Note: I apologize for my bad english. I'm learning yet.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if you can group simple buttons. But you can define a click function in each button to change the value of button in a Bollean Array (with lenght equals amount of button.)

In this case, you will have acess a boolean value directly for a index.

Comment: I don't think well. I need to know what button is pressed and take actions, but there are a lot of buttons and each button has a action different. If button one is pressed, action will be different and I'm searching of way to don't do a lot of conditions.

Comment: Well, in this case, you can create states to definy after each click the next  event or group of state to define the next event.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923767/simple-state-machine-example-in-c