# Architecture for single activity Android library

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, android-library, android-architecture-components

I have a simple use case where my Android library will be initialized on app startup from the Application class. On initialization, I start a file download in the background which can take around 10-15secs. I need to show the content of this file in my `FileDetailsActivity`.

And meanwhile, the file is downloading if the user navigates to the `FileDetailsActivity`, I've to show a loader in this activity till downloads get completed. If the file is already downloaded I've to simply show it in `FileDetailsActivity`.

`FileDetailsActivity.java` - Android activity which show file details.
`FileDownloadHelper.java` - Simple thread class which downloads the file and saves it in internal storage.
`MyLib.java` - Library public file through which library can be used. Contains 2 methods:

- init() - Initialize library and starts the file download.
- showDetails() - Starts `FileDetailsActivity` activity.

I need help in creating architecture for this use case. Like, how can I sync the download status(downloaded, downloading, error) with my activity from `FileDownloadHelper`  etc.

Comment: Use service to download file, and Send Local BroadCasts of different states to activity.

Comment: Use state machine.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך any blog or tutorials where I can read about state machine?

Comment: This will be helpul: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923767/simple-state-machine-example-in-c