# C# Different Behaviours in a method according to the variable state

Tags: c#

```
public class Tile
{
   State state ;

   public void OnStep()
   {
       if(state == State.normal) { // Do something; }
       else if(state == State.empty) { // Do something; }
       else if(state == State.hazard) { // Do something; }

   }
}
```

Basically, OnStep will do different behaviours according to the 'state' variable.

I really want to remove those 'if statements' yet I do not want to change Tile class into an abstract class. It works now but I want to know if there is a better technique to manage this. Currently 'State' is enum. ( I am wondering if there is anything that can bind both state and action at the same time ).

Comment: _"I really want to remove those 'if statements' yet I do not want to change Tile class into an abstract class."_ How would that be related?

Comment: _"Currently 'State' is enum. ( I am wondering if there is anything that can bind both state and action at the same time )"_ Sure. For one, you could use switch instead of if/else. But that's only a minor change. But then you could use for example strategy pattern ... basically that's a statemachine, right?

Comment: It really depends on the nature of those `//Do something`s. If they can each be replaced by a parameterless method inside the same class than perhaps `state` could just be an `Action` instead that is update to reflect which method should be called next. Also depends on what else `state` is being used for. This is the problem when you so far abstract your example from your problem that so many answers *may* be possible.

Comment: You're options are, use a `switch`, use a `Dicitonary<State, Action>` or as you seem to indicate is not what you want to do, create subclasses on `Tile` for each `State` that `Tile` can have (this only makes sense if `State` is immutable)

Comment: @Fildor, at first I want to make Tile into abstract class and create different child classes for each state ( instead of if statements )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923767/simple-state-machine-example-in-c

Comment: What does `State` look like?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou _"Currently 'State' is enum"_ - from Question.

Comment: @Fildor - it threw me off because it is using lowercase names for the enum field, instead of Uppercase which is the standard, so it could have been a `struct` with readonly fields like you have in Java.

Answer (score 1):

So I get you want to extract the logic away from `Tile` class ...

```
public class Tile
{
   private IState _state;

   public void OnStep()
   {
       _state = _state.Step();
   }
}

public interface IState
{
    IState Step();
}

public class NormalStep: IStep
{
    public IStep Step()
    { 
       /*Step logic*/ 
       // Just an example
       if( encounter.HazardousObject ) return new HazardStep();
       return this;
    }
}

public class HazardStep: IStep
{
    public IStep Step(){ /*Step logic*/ }
}

public class EmptyStep: IStep
{
    public IStep Step(){ /*Step logic*/ }
}
```

That would be the simplest scenario. From here you always can get more complex. For example with state data ...

To pick up on madreflection's comments: Everything has its price.

In this case ...

- you get rid of the `if` statements.
- you "bundle" behavior with type (== state)

But you pay with substantially more code, more classes, more interfaces. So you always need to take into consideration with what to go *and live*. What if you have to change/add something in two week's time? Will you be able to without problem?

One last thing: Please do mind, that the above example is just a brief and very simple "something like this". It is *of course* **far away from being production-quality**.

Comment: In other words, learn the Gang of Four design patterns -- as one should do anyway -- and then select the State pattern to solve this problem.

Comment: If you say it that way .... yes, basically that. @madreflection

Comment: I mean, there's nothing inherently wrong with a stack of `if` statements for someone who's just setting out. But there seems to be this obsession with doing things with less code without any cost. It rarely is without cost. So here, you have less code int `OnStep`, but it had to cost something, and that's in what replaces the `if` statements, the State classes. New programmers need to stop obsessing over "less code" until they've learned enough, because they're not yet equipped (or willing) to pay for it with a maintainable design.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: That said, source generation usually lets you have your cake (less code) and eat it too (automatically maintainable and as efficient as you can write it).

Comment: Then the cost is the knowledge and effort it takes to write a source generator, which is a much more advanced topic than basic design patterns.

Comment: @Blindy, agreed, yet nothing I'd give the newbie in the team.

Comment: I don't know man, you have to give them *something*. What could be better than a completely new piece of code with no dependencies on your other code that is very easily and strongly testable by design?

Comment: @Blindy Depends on the person, I guess. I know some newbies at ours that would totally excel and others that would just explode. I basically follow the rule "learn to crawl before you learn to run".

Answer (score 0):

I think using a `switch` statement produces the cleanest code

```
public enum State
{
    Empty,
    Normal,
    Hazard,
}

public class Tile
{
    public State State { get; set; }

    public void OnStep()
    {
        switch (State)
        {
            case State.Empty:
                // do things
                break;
            case State.Normal:
                // do things
                break;
            case State.Hazard:
                // do things
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Unknown state {State}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not meant to be a "better" solution, just suggesting another way to do it.

You may name individual action methods in some convention e.g. `RunNormalState()`, so inside `OnStep()` you can use Reflection to invoke it.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If there are other options, reflection is very rarely the best (performance, maintainability, readability) of them.

Comment: Well, bad performance yes, but readability is OK. You still keep all related logics inside a single class, and it's easy to extend or override methods when you have subclass of Tile. Reflection itself is not that uncommon. Numerous frameworks convert file paths / URL routes and invoke corresponding controller methods via reflection.