# Good way to handle login events in order

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a login system which need to :

1. Connect.
2. Wait until it is connected.
3. Send a login request.
4. Wait for a response of this request.
5. Send another kind of request.
6. Wait for this request
7. Go on!

What would be a good way to handle this scenario knowing the networking stack are events driven which mean basically that events are sent when i receive data, when i am connected, etc.

I am wondering if i should go with Async methods or only a simple loop ?

Comment: I think you haven't given us enough information. What type of application are you trying to do? Windows form? During this process the application should be responsive?

Comment: This is a WPF application sorry and yes during the process the application should be responsive.

Comment: Then the answer from @Murtuza is very good. If you need some example take a look to [this server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx) and [this client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going asynchronous or not largely depends on the type of GUI you are offering to your user. If you are implementing this functionality in a console application, there is no need to go for it as console always do one thing at a time. On the other hand, if you are offering a full functional GUI to your user, it is important that the GUI is responsive while your application is trying to connect.

Apart from that, when you are dealing with networking and communication through sockets, it is a good idea to use packet headers. i.e. you should send a packet header first saying the server that you are going send the login request and such header should contain mainly two information 1. what kind of packet will follow and 2. What is the length of following packet. Same way, server will respond with packet header first.

Asynchronous is a good idea and you should try to implement asynchronous methods with networking to gracefully handle user interactions and make the GUI more responsive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on WPF 4.5 then the new async/await constructs will be perfect for your scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The GUI responsiveness can be kept by calling `synchronous methods` on a `background` thread.

Asynchronous calls are basically useful if you plan on giving the user a chance to `'Cancel'` its request [ if the server responses are too slow ]

Sync:

```
|----A-----| |-----B-----------| |-------C------|
```

Async:

```
|----A-----|
   |-----B-----------| 
       |-------C------|
```

Considering that you need to finish a step before going to the next, i think async methods will not give you any significant advantages (other than the ability to cancel request).

Answer (score 0):

coroutines is a nice trick

allows you to loop through async tasks

[Coroutines in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599361/coroutines-in-c-sharp)