# state machines in .net

Tags: .net

can any on explain me what are state machines in .net

Comment: are you referring to State Machine Workflows? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735945(VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [Finite-state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine), they're essentially language-independent. The implementation would differ by language, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using the Yield keyword to create a state machine you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1194853/119477)

Note: Eric Lippert's answer contra-indicates using them.